# Литература по оценкам сложности

Tags: книги, сложность

Хотел бы разобраться в этой теме максимально подробно, можете ли посоветовать подходящую литературу, хотелось бы, чтобы с примерами. Каким образом вы сами разбирались в данной теме?

Comment: "Кормен. Алгоритмы." Первая глава или две.

Comment: Почему отрицательный рейтинг? мой вопрос не соответствует правилам?

Comment: Хоть вопрос и соответствует правилам, однако, здесь почему-то не очень любят вопросы общего характера (которые не описывают конкретную проблему). Вот вам кто-то и влепил минус, несмотря на то, что это отражается и на его собственном рейтинге.